# Как заставить искать название метода по части имени в xcode?

Tags: xcode

Что нужно сделать, чтобы xcode в выпадающем списке функций выдавал не только те функции, которые начинаются с введённых символов, но и те, что содержат эти символы?

К примеру, я хочу вызвать метод selectToMark, и помню, что в названии есть "mark". Набираю "ma", но в списке функций нет нужной.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот если писать название метода с первого символа, то тогда нужный метод появится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но это же чёртов ад - помнить все названия функций с первого символа. Наверняка есть какой-то способ настроить это по-человечески.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для Xcode есть плагин называется FuzzyAutocomplete. Делает как раз то вы хотите, на Xcode 6 прекрасно работал, на Xcode 7 еще не пробовал.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!!! Запустил на 7м - работает! :)